# Use django model in another application

Tags: django, templates, model

I have two different apps for homepage(main) and events(events)

In the models.py of I have a class "Event".

In the events/views.py

```
def all_events(request):
events_list = Event.objects.all()
return render(request, 'event-listing.html', {'events_list': events_list})
```

which worked just fine.

But I want to do the following in the homepage(main) application's views.py

```
def all_events(request):
events_list = Event.objects.all()
return render(request, 'index.html', {'events_list': events_list})
```

I imported the following:

```
from BV.events.models import Event
```

but it says :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BV.events'
```

My goal is to show the events in the homepage.

Comment: `from events.models import Event`?

Comment: tried that but events is not recognized in main/views.py

Comment: Could you edit question to show structure of your project?

Comment: Have you registered both apps in settings.py?